# Regex To Remove Script And Style Tags + Content Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I've a scenario where i have complete web pages having javascript, css and html. I need to remove the script and style tags plus their contents completely. I have achieved this in PHP using the following regex:

```
 $str = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $html); 
 preg_replace('#<style(.*?)>(.*?)</style>#is', '', $str);
```

But can't get it done in javascript. I want to have the equivalent of

```
 <script(.*?)>(.*?)</script> //in javascript
```

I want to replace all their occurrences within html.
I have stripped out the others html tags with this

```
 pureText.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, ''); //just a reference
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to have the equivalent of
>   `<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script> //in javascript`

```
/<script([\S\s]*?)>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/ig
```

Use `[\S\s]*?` instead of `.*?` in your regex because javascript won't support `s` modifier (*DOTALL modifier*). `[\S\s]*?` would match any space or non-space character zero or more times non-greedily.

Answer (score 3):

[Don't use regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) for this. It is much slower and less reliable than manipulating the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model#Applications).

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var css = document.getElementsByTagName('style');

for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++)
{
    scripts[i].parentItem.removeChild(scripts[i]);
}
for(var j = 0; j < css.length; j++)
{
    css[j].parentItem.removeChild(css[j]);
}
```

Comment: That would worth a try, I'm getting the html document dynamically through ajax though.