# JS: How to remove style tags and their content from an HTML string, using regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove the entire content of style tags from an html string, in multiple occurrences. I can't use a DOM parser for it.

How could i do this, in JavaScript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: What is your use case? Why can't you use a dom parser?

Comment: Because i'm fetching gigantic html files, and i want to strip them out of junk before i parse them in Cheerio, hoping it will improve my memory consumption problem in Nodejs. I'm building a web scraper that performs a lot of http requests in parallel, and some sites have html files with up to 2 million characters(mostly junk, as i said). I hope that striping the junk before parsing the DOM, will improve my memory situation.

Comment: So you already use a DOM parser (cheerio), but you have a problem with its memory consumption? Then you should consider modifying the parser so that it drops styles (and everything else you consider "junk") immediately instead of appending it to its DOM, not try something with regex. (Why regex!?)

Answer (score 11):

For those that land here in 2020 this worked for me.

```
string.replace(/(<style[\w\W]+style>)/g, "")
```

As Bergi alluded to in the OP comments thought, this should be regarded as a last resort if there are no better options. RegEx is not the best way to deal with HTML.

Comment: Careful with this. If you have multiple `<style>` tags, it'll wipe out anything between the first and last tags.

Answer (score 6):

```js
    var string = "<style>someHTMLStuff</style> non style <html>stuff</html>"

    var s = string.replace(/<style.*?<\/style>/g, '')
    
    console.log(s);
```

I am assuming you wanted the entire style tag removed, not just its contents

Edit: quotes

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Is it possible it needs some adjustment, being that the strings breaks to multiple lines?

Comment: @sheff2k1 javascript regex doesn't use quotes, updated my answer

Answer (score 4):

`<style([\S\s]*?)>([\S\s]*?)<\/style>`

https://regex101.com/r/C28OPE/1

This worked for me even with multiple  tags. [credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26553146/692466)

Answer (score -2):

To replace all style attributes in a HTML element (innerHTML) :

```
<div id="el">
  <p style="font-weight:bold">Line 1</p>
  <p style="color:red">Line 2</p>
</div>

//script
let element = document.getElementById('el')
element.innerHTML.replace(/style=\".*"/gm,'')
```

This will remove all elements style attribute in element by id el.